# y-axis label in morris chart

Tags: html, css, angular, morris.js

I have a morris graph in angular application which shows data on page load. I tried to have name 'Population' on y-axis using html, css like this:

[image]

But when the page is initially loading, this span 'Population' is moving upwards into other div which is above this and when the graph is loaded, it is coming into it's position.

```css
    #demandGraph{
      margin-left: 4%;
      height:100%;
    }
     #demandGraph p {
      position:relative;
      float:left;
      width:50%;
      border-radius:5px;
      -moz-border-radius:5px;
      vertical-align: center;
      margin-left: -3%;
    }
     #demandGraph p span {
      font-size: 15px;
      color: '#606060';
      width:100%; /* same as height of .rotateObj */
      -webkit-transform-origin:84px 70px;
      display:inline-block;
      -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
      text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="card-body" id="Graph">
        <div id ="graphElement"></div>
        <p><span>Population</span></p>
```

I want the 'Population' to be in this graph div until the graph loads and should not move upwards into other div. How can I achieve this?